# Why is setting my UINavigationBar's background image affecting the size of the navigation bar?

Tags: objective-c, image, user-interface, uinavigationbar

I'm doing something like this:

```
UIImage *barBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:
                                    backgroundImage
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

And the resulting UINavigationBar is much larger than the standard navigation bar. I'm aware that my image size might be the problem. Is there any way to take care of this programmatically?

Comment: I have the same problem..did you end up solving this?

Comment: I've got it now. If your retina image is 640x88, just specify the name in the code without the @2x included. For some reason, the system won't resize it properly if you include the '@2x' in the code (or if you name it something without the '@2x')

Answer (score 4):

This is how I set the `UINavigationController`'s `navigationBar` background image.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:LIGHTBROWN];
```

**`navbar.png`** is `320x44` and respectively `640x88` for `navbar@2x.png`.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this link to make your code compatible with iOS4, 5 and 6: http://robert-varga.com/?p=735

You just have to make in Photoshop or other software a rectangular with the size of 320x44 or 640x88 (for retina display) and import it to your project